# Tracing for Debezium Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am using debezium-connector-mysql via confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base docker image. Connector I have installed through confluence hub.

I need to add tracing to this connector. I use opentelemetry-javaagent to reach this stuff. It works fine, at least locally, but I need to pass some additional info from outbox table(value form row record) to trace. How I can do it ?

I have already tried this tracing.span.context.field option from [docs](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/integrations/tracing.html) for connector configuration, but it looks like does not work

Comment: Not really related to your answer, but I'm sharing an information since I understood you are using the source connector for outbox pattern, and I thing that connector is not safe for a use where you need to capture every single event from your table, infact query based CDC is not meant for that, you would need log based CDC like Debezium. Here is a reference https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6790276647267405825?commentUrn=urn%3Ali%3Acomment%3A%28activity%3A6790276647267405825%2C6790562617032286208%29

Comment: This issue also explains that there is no guarantee of not losing some rows in auto-incrementing mode https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/172.